# conditionally validate a form field in django

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, conditional-statements

I have a textfield that renders in a django form.  This text field can have different types of data like ip addresses, urls, regular text, etc.  Depending on a previous drop down's input in the form, how do I conditionally validate the text field?

For example if I choose ip address in the drop down, how do I then conditionally throw a validation error when input besides when an ip address is entered in the text field?

Comment: [This should help you](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @karthikr:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ContactForm, self).clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if "help" not in subject:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Did not send for 'help' in "
                        "the subject despite CC'ing yourself.")

        # Always return the full collection of cleaned data.
        return cleaned_data
```

It's all explained here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other